# Валидация мобильного номера телефона

Tags: php, алгоритм, валидация

Что мы знаем о номере телефоне:

1. Номер может начинаться как с + так и без в зависимости от страны
2. Код разный и может быть разной длины
3. Длина самого номера может быть разной
4. (вы можете дополнить этот список в комментариях)

Какой же всё-таки должен быть алгоритм для валидации любого мобильного номера?

Чтобы не превращать тему в обширную дискуссию, пожалуйста, пишите примеры в ответ.

Comment: [giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php](https://packagist.org/packages/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php#user-content-installation)

Comment: Вы знакомы с этой библиотекой? Просит в экземпляре регион `$swissNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse($swissNumberStr, "CH");`. А как проверить валидность без страны?

Comment: Лично не работал, а порекомендовал её по отзывам.

Comment: Ну хорошая библиотека. Спасибо)

Comment: Валидация номера мобильника производится отправкой на него смс и вводом пользователем полученного кода. Всё остальное - от лукавого. Вот только как некоторые компании типа Uber отличают реальные сотовые номера от виртуальных voip - этого я, увы, не знаю